# Tails of Cauchy sequences, and their closures

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

Consider a metric space $(S,d)$, its completion $\tilde S$, and its closure $\overline{S}$. (By *closure* I imply: *closure in completion*.)

In the standard topology (one induced by the metric, i.e., based on open balls), we have $\tilde{S} = \overline{S}$. (Please correct me if I am wrong.)

Also consider a Cauchy sequence $\left\{  y_n \right\}$ and its tails
$$
Y_i\,=\,\left\{ y_i,\, y_{i+1},\;.\,.\,.\, \right\}\,\;.
$$
The tails are nested,
$$
Y_{i+1} \subset Y_i\,\;,
$$
but are not necessarily closed.  Their diameters are defined as
$$
\operatorname{diam}\, Y_i\,\equiv\,\operatorname{sup}_{m,n\leq i}\,d(y_m,\,y_n)\,\;.
$$
Likewise, the diameters of their completions (= closures) are
$$
\operatorname{diam}\, \overline{Y}_i\,\equiv\,\operatorname{sup}_{m,n\leq i}\,\left(\,d(y_m,\,y_n), \,  d(y_m,\,y)\,\right)\,\;,
$$
$y$ being the limit of $\left\{y_i\right\}$. This limit is not necessarily in the space $S$, but is in $\tilde{S}$.

The sequence is Cauchy, so the tails satisfy
$$
\operatorname{diam}\, {Y}_i\,\longrightarrow\,0\,\;.
$$

QUESTION:

How to prove the same for the completions (= closures, on this occasion) -- i.e., to show that
$$
\operatorname{diam}\, {\overline{Y}}_i\,\longrightarrow\,0\,\;.
$$

My understanding is that
$$
\operatorname{diam}\, \overline{Y}_i\,\leq \operatorname{diam}\, Y_i\,+\,\sup_{m\geq i}\,d(y_m,\,y)\,\;.
$$
If this is correct, my question may be put in a simpler form: how to prove that
$$
\sup_{m\geq i}\,d(y_m,\,y)\,\longrightarrow\,0~~~\mbox{for}~~~i\longrightarrow\infty
$$
Is this so simply by definition of the limit?

Comment: I am unable to correct the sentence “In the standard topology, we have $\tilde{S} = \overline{S}$” since I don't know what it means.

Comment: What do you mean by the "closure" of $S$? $S$ is of course closed, i.e., $\operatorname{cl}_S S = S$. So you need to be more precise -- closure with respect to what?

Comment: Presumably, you mean the closure of $S$ in the completion?

Comment: @MPW Yes, good point, I shall explain that this a closure w.r.t. completion.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, in completion. I shall fix this in the text.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos By *standard topology* I imply the one induced by the metric: the metric induces distance, the distance defines open balls, thence open sets, thence a topology. By $\tilde{S} = \overline{S}$ I imply that the closure $\overline{S}$ of S in the completion $\tilde{S}$ coincides with the completion $\tilde{S}$.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:** What does it *mean* for $y$ to be the limit of the sequence $(y_i)$?